# Почему не декодируется openssl_public_decrypt()

Tags: php, openssl

Почему не декодируется если использую openssl_public_decrypt($crypttext, $decrypted, $publickey), НО срабатывает если использую openssl_private_decrypt($crypttext, $decrypted, $privatekey);

```
<?php



if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) )
{
    echo "SECURE: This page is being accessed through a secure connection.<br><br>";
}
else
{
    echo "UNSECURE: This page is being access through an unsecure connection.<br><br>";
}

// Create the keypair -- Генерирует новый секретный ключ
$res=openssl_pkey_new();

// Get private key -- Получает строку с ключем в формате PEM
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privatekey);

// Get public key
$publickey=openssl_pkey_get_details($res); // Получает массив с детальной информацией о ключе

$publickey=$publickey["key"];

echo "Private Key:<BR>$privatekey<br><br>Public Key:<BR>$publickey<BR><BR>";

$cleartext = '1234 5678 9012 3456';

echo "Clear text:<br>$cleartext<BR><BR>";

// Шифрование данных открытым ключём
openssl_public_encrypt($cleartext, $crypttext, $publickey);
echo "Crypt text:<br>$crypttext<BR><BR>";

//openssl_private_decrypt($crypttext, $decrypted, $privatekey);
openssl_public_decrypt($crypttext, $decrypted, $publickey);
echo "Decrypted text:<BR>$decrypted<br><br>";

?>
```

Comment: Очень может быть потому что там строковое значение ключа. Попробуйте использовать openssl_get_publickey для его получения.

Comment: В смысле вместо $publickey=openssl_pkey_get_details($res); использовать 
$publickey=openssl_get_publickey($res);

Comment: Видимо, вам придется еще добавить вызов openssl_error_string для того чтобы понять ошибку и масштаб той конфигурации что у вас имеется ...

Comment: error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value

Comment: Вот отсюда и надо копать [дальше](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8865). Видимо что-то в вашем конф файле не нравится [модулю openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076800/openssl-pkey-new-throws-error-configuration-file-routinesnconf-get-stringno-va)

Comment: А почему тогда openssl_private_decrypt() нравится?( Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать.

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще, читаю мануал
penssl_public_encrypt() шифрует data открытым ключем key и сохраняет в crypted. Впоследствии расшифровать их можно функцией openssl_private_decrypt().